# John 7:31 When Christ appears, will he do more signs than this man has done?

Tags: john, christology, messiah, israel, second-temple-judaism

How did the people come to have the expectation that the Messiah, when he appears, should be accompanied by a multitude of miraculous signs?

> Yet many of the people believed in him. They said, “When the Christ appears, will he do more signs than this man has done?”
> **-John 7:31**

Answer (score 1):

The miraculous signs and wonders were perceived to accompany any divine revelation as was often recorded in the OT such as, Ex 7:3, Num 14:11, Deut 6:22, 7:19, 10:21, 26:8, 29:3, 34:11, Neh 9:10, Job 5:8-11, Ps 105:27, 135:9, Isa 8:18, Jer 32:20, 21, Dan 6:27 recall the miracles done for ancient Israel, eg, to free them from Egypt.

In particular, several passages explicitly speak of a future worker of miracles:

- Isa 35:4-6 - Say to those with anxious hearts: “Be strong, do not fear! Behold, your God will come with vengeance. With divine retribution He will come to save you.” Then the eyes of the blind will be opened and the ears of the deaf unstopped. Then the lame will leap like a deer and the mute tongue will shout for joy.
- Isa 61:1-3 - The Spirit of the Lord GOD is on Me, because the LORD has anointed Me to preach good news to the poor. He has sent Me to bind up the brokenhearted, to proclaim liberty to the captives and freedom to the prisoners, to proclaim the year of the LORD’s favor and the day of our God’s vengeance, to comfort all who mourn, to console the mourners in Zion— to give them a crown of beauty for ashes, the oil of joy for mourning, and a garment of praise for a spirit of despair. So they will be called oaks of righteousness, the planting of the LORD, that He may be glorified.
- Micah 7:15 - As in the days when you came out of Egypt, I will show My wonders.

The latter was quoted by Jesus as His Keynote address/sermon at the start of ministry as recorded in Luke 4:18, 19.

Jesus also appears to allude to Isa 35 when questioned by John's disciples using His miracles as a partial proof of His authenticity in Matt 11:4-6 -

> Jesus replied, “Go back and report to John what you hear and see:
> **The blind receive sight, the lame walk, the lepers are cleansed, the deaf hear, the dead are raised, and the good news is preached to the
> poor**. Blessed is the one who does not fall away on account of Me.

Answer (score 1):

Moses performed many signs when he brought the children of Israel out of Egypt.  Thus, to be like Moses would expect signs.

> And consider today (since I am not speaking to your children who have not known or seen it), consider the discipline of the LORD your God, his greatness, his mighty hand and his outstretched arm, 3 his signs and his deeds that he did in Egypt to Pharaoh the king of Egypt and to all his land, 4 and what he did to the army of Egypt, to their horses and to their chariots, how he made the water of the Red Sea flow over them as they pursued after you, and how the LORD has destroyed them to this day, 5 and what he did to you in the wilderness, until you came to this place, 6 and what he did to Dathan and Abiram the sons of Eliab, son of Reuben, how the earth opened its mouth and swallowed them up, with their households, their tents, and every living thing that followed them, in the midst of all Israel. 7 For your eyes have seen all the great work of the LORD that he did.
> (Deut. 11:2–7, ESV)

> “The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brothers—it is to him you shall listen— ... I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brothers. And I will put my words in his mouth, and he shall speak to them all that I command him.
> (Deut 18:15,18, ESV)

> Philip found Nathanael and said to him, “We have found him of whom Moses in the Law and also the prophets wrote, Jesus of Nazareth, the son of Joseph.”
> (John 1:45, ESV)